# Remove left padding from legend element

Tags: html, css

I want fieldsets and divs containing content to be visually equal. I use YUI 3.4.1 reset CSS and I have the following markup:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Hello world!</legend>
    <div>Lorem ipsum</div>                
</fieldset>
<div>
    <h3>Hello world!</h3>
    <div>Lorem ipsum</div>                
</div>
```

In IE7 the legend element it slightly indented. I've tried to remove padding, margin and text-indentation.

```
fieldset,div{ 
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
legend,h3{ 
    background-color: yellow; 
    width: 200px; 
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Are there other properties I'm missing here, that can help solve the problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/DBhQb/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On CSS file of [HTML5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) `legend` is styled in this way

```
legend { border: 0; *margin-left: -7px; padding: 0; white-space: normal; }
```

`*margin-left: -7px;` should make the trick, since it's a css hack for IE<8

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
fieldset , legend{ padding:0px; margin:0px;}
```